# SVD and projection

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares, svd, projection

[image]

I am working on part c of the problem above. I have figured out the expression for sum of square which is $ min \sum_{i} ||x_{i} - (x_{i}^{T} u)u||^{2}_{2}$, but could not work out how to use SVD for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that by the Pythagorean theorem and using the fact that $u$ is a unit vector,
$$
\sum_i \|x_i - (x_i^Tu)u\|^2 = \sum_i (\|x_i\|^2 - \|(x_i^Tu)u\|^2)\\
= \sum_{i} \|x_i\|^2 - \sum_i |x_i^T u|^2\\
= \operatorname{tr}(X^TX) - \|Xu\|^2.
$$
Use the SVD to find the unit vector $u$ that maximizes $\|Xu\|^2$ and thereby minimizes the cost function.